# The taylor series is given determine $a_n$ for which x converges to f(x)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, taylor-expansion

The taylor series of the function f(x) = $1-\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}$ around x = 0 is given by  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$

determine $a_n$ for all n $\geq$ 0 and give for which value of x the series converges to f(x)

I've come to this result $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}x^{2n}}{n!}$ =  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$

Anyone got ideas how to solve this further on?

Comment: You are trying to find radius of convergence right?

Comment: Unfortunately, you $a_n$'s are wrong.

Comment: @J.Doe: you just edited, didn't you ?

Comment: Also fix your $a^n$.

Comment: No, pay attention. $a^n\leftrightarrow a_n$.

Comment: "have to find $a_n$ for which it converges" doesn't make sense. The $a_n$ are known. The question was solved by Gary Moon.

Comment: @J.Doe: this does not address the issue of convergence. And did you, mh, "guess" the coefficients ?

Comment: Tell us how you obtained the coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that next you want to find the radius of convergence $R$. You can use the ratio test to see that $R = \infty$. Consider
$$\bigg\lvert \frac{(-1)^{n+2}x^{2(n+1)}}{(n+1)!} \cdot \frac{n!}{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n}}\bigg\rvert= \frac{\lvert x \rvert^2}{n+1} \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty.$$

Edit: Since $R=\infty$, it follows that the power series converges (to $f(x)$) for all real $x$.

Comment: I misstated my question i meant you have to find an for which it converges

Answer (score 0):

The exponential function has the well-known Taylor series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$ which converges for all real values.

Substituting $-x^2$ for $x$, you will get an entire series, which is indeed the Taylor series of $e^{-x^2}$.

You can conclude.